# ArcGIS Composite Geocoder Search by Address or Streets Intersection

Tags: arcgis-desktop, geocoding, composite

I'm struggling with the configuration of a composite geocoder. I have a table of address points consisting of

- House number
- Street name

and a table of street segments consisting of

- Street name
- Left cross street name
- Right cross street name

Is it possible to create a composite locator that uses the address point as its primary geocoder, then falls back to the street name geocoder to locate the intersection of two streets?

Comment: I think you might need to create two separate geocoders, and write a "wrapper" function to decide which one to use. Test for the presence of a number and street name, and if so call the first geocoder, falling back to the segments geocoder.

Comment: As suggested above, but the "wrapper" is a third geocoder that references the first two

Answer (score 1):

Stephen is correct in that you must first create two separate geocoders with create address locator. Then you create the composite address locator (which in this case is the wrapper they are referring to) and add the two locators you created to the participating address locators box.  (see the image below)  Then once you geocode your data it will read from the address points and if it doesn't match it will then geocode via the street segments anything left over will be unmatched.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your response, I'm struggling with this issue as I am trying to  use the geocoder via the geocoder toolbar. The composite geocoder just seems to use the first geocoder, and doesn't appear to 'fall back' to the other(s). So if none are found in the first one, it doesn't find any results.

Comment: Also, reverse geocoding does work. For example, in ArcGIS Pro, I can click "What's Here" at an intersection, and it will give me 6TH AVE NE & 1ST ST NE but when I paste that into the locate search box, it returns no results.

Comment: I should also note, I don't want the user to have to type in a city/zip etc since all the addresses are local to one city, so I didn't use those fields when I created the geocoder.